# Laravel 5.4 sorting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I've got 2 columns, Model and Action.
First thing I would like to achieve is to order the model from A to Z.

I'm doing that with

```
orderBy('model', 'ASC')
```

Then I would like to order the action column on index, create, store etc.
I've got a query, and i'me trying to sort the results in order: index, create, store, show, edit, update, destroy, [**everything else**].

However the result i'm getting is:
[**everything else**], index, create, store, show, edit, update, destroy

Query:

```
Permission::orderBy('model', 'ASC')->orderByRaw("FIELD(action, 'index', 'create', 'store', 'show', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy')")->get();
```

Result should be something like:

- model 1, index
- model 1, create
- model 1, store
- etc
- model 1, everything else
- model 2, index
- model 2, create
- model 2, store
- etc
- model 2, everything else

Has anyone got an idea how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `orderBy` method allows you to sort the result of the query by a given column. The first argument to the orderBy method should be the column you wish to sort by, while the second argument controls the direction of the sort and may be either `asc` or `desc`, check the example:

```
$users = DB::table('table')
->orderBy('name', 'desc')  // You can pass as many columns as you want
->get();
```